# XSLT Transformation for outbound it's not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to make a XSLT tranformation for an outbout xml. I've followed a tutorial but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PublishITEM xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance" creationDateTime="2020-02-25T11:12:05+01:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" 
messageID="318921582625525794116" maximoVersion="7 6 20190514-1348 V7611-365" event="1">
   <ITEMSet>
     <ITEM action="Add">
       <ATTACHONISSUE>0</ATTACHONISSUE>
     </ITEM>
     <ITEM action="Add">
       <ATTACHONISSUE>1</ATTACHONISSUE>
     </ITEM>
   </ITEMSet>
 </PublishITEM>
```

The XSL Transformation I've done is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result- 
prefixes="mea" 
xmlns:mea="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml- 
declaration="yes"/> 
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="mea:PublishITEM"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mea:PublishITEM">
<xsl:apply-templates select="mea:ITEMSet"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mea:ITEMSet">
<xsl:apply-templates select="mea:ITEM"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mea:ITEM">
<PARAM>
<xsl:apply-templates select="mea:ATTACHONISSUE"/>

</PARAM>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mea:ATTACHONISSUE">
<CD-NAME><xsl:value-of select="."/></CD-NAME>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don;t understand what I'm doing wrong. I've tried different online sites to test is. One of the errors I received was: **No stylesheet associated to this object**

Forget to mention the result I want is:

```
<PARAM>
<CD-NAME>0</CD-NAME>
</PARAM>
<PARAM>
<CD-NAME>1</CD-NAME>
</PARAM>
```

Also it's possible to have an if? for example..if the value is 0 in the outpu put false, if it's 1 true?
I also added the XSL with the corrections suggested

Comment: *" I've tried different online sites to tes"* Try here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of templates in there that could be omitted just by using the default templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:mea="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" exclude-result-prefixes="mea">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/> 

<xsl:template match="mea:ITEM">
    <PARAM>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="mea:ATTACHONISSUE"/>
    </PARAM>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mea:ATTACHONISSUE">
    <CD-NAME><xsl:value-of select="."/></CD-NAME>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4HW

Comment: Thanks! But  if I need to check if the value is 1 print true if is 0 print false? How can I do that ?

Comment: Then call  `boolean(number())` in the select expression: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4HW/2

Comment: I would be worried about not starting with the root element, because: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4HW/3

Comment: Well, it is possible to set up `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>` as the default in XSLT 3 or to set up the equivalent templates in XSLT 1 or 2.

Comment: What is wrong in my version? <xsl:template match="mea:ATTACHONISSUE">
 <xsl:choose> 
  <xsl:if test="mea:ATTACHONISSUE= 'ON'"> 
   <CD-NAME><xsl:value-of select="1"</CD-NAME>
  </xsl:if> 
  <xsl:if test="mea:STATUS= 'OFF'"> 
   <CD-NAME><xsl:value-of select="5"</CD-NAME>
  </xsl:if>    
 </xsl:choose>

Comment: @Mircea, inside of the template matching an element or any node that node is the context node so you just use `. = 'On'. And of course the right combination of XSLT elements is `xsl:choose` with `xsl:when`, not `xsl:if`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will keep only one param. Thank you a lot. I manage to do it and I've understand more on how it's working. But now..I have used this xsl in my app and after the transformation i still have<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> at the beggginig, even if I have omit declarations=yes. On the online tool provided by you, the result it's as expected but not on my app :) do you have any idea on whats might going on ?

Comment: @Mircea, please ask such issues as a separate question where you detail the way you use XSLT, i.e. the XSLT processor, the API, the editor or IDE you use, with the relevant tags.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, remove the trailing `/` character in:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="mea:PublishITEM/"/>
```

and:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="mea:ITEMSet/"/>
```

and:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="mea:ITEM/"/>
```

Next, you will want to remove the `<PARAM>` wrapper from one of the two templates that output it. And also add a `exclude-result-prefixes="mea"` attribute to your `xsl:stylesheet` element.

---

Of course, you could shorten the whole thing to just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:mea="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"
exclude-result-prefixes="mea">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/> 

<xsl:template match="/mea:PublishITEM">
    <PARAM>
        <CD-NAME>
            <xsl:value-of select="mea:ITEMSet/mea:ITEM/mea:ATTACHONISSUE"/>
        </CD-NAME>
    </PARAM>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(assuming there will always be only one `ATTACHONISSUE` element in the XML input).

Comment: and in case I will have more items? Every item will have a different ATTACHONISSUE. I should add for each ? for the item node ?

Comment: I cannot answer this, because I don't know what the result should be then. Please edit your question and show an example of XML that has more than one item, and the expected result of the transformation.

Comment: I've added it but beside for eachwhich is not mandatory, I need to check if the value is 1 print true if is 0 print false.

Comment: Then why doesn't your expected result show that? Note also that the result you show is not a well-formed XML document because it does not have a single root element.